# Flask: ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from 'src.app' , Impossible to import db from the app

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

[image]

above is the structure of my project.
I can't import db from my app to database.py file it seems that the import don't succeed
and I don't undestand why this doesn't work
If someone can help me It wil be 
I'm working with flask,flask-sqlalchemy and python3.7

the app.py file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, session, redirect
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
import os
from .database import Users, Questions
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(24)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://christ:azsxcrc@localhost:3306/questionapp'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

classActive = 'active'
classActives = {'classActivehome': classActive, 'classActivelogin': classActive,
            'classActiveregister': classActive, 'classActiveask': classActive,
            'classActiveanswer': classActive, 'classActiveunan': classActive,
            'classActiveuser': classActive}


def get_current_user():
user_object = None

if 'user' in session:
    user = session['user']
    user_result = Users.query.filter(Users.name == user).first()
    user_object['id'] = user_result.id
    user_object['name'] = user_result.name
    user_object['email'] = user_result.email
    user_object['password'] = user_result.password
    user_object['expert'] = user_result.expert
    user_object['admin'] = user_result.admin

return user_object


@app.teardown_appcontext
def shutdown_session(exception=None):
     db.session.remove()


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def index():
   user = get_current_user()

q = Questions.query.filter(Questions.answer_text is not None)

questions_list = {}

for question in q:
    questions_list['id'] = question.id
    questions_list['question_text'] = question.question_text
    questions_list['answer_text'] = question.answer_text
    questions_list['asker'] = question.asker.name
    questions_list['expert'] = question.expert.name

return render_template('home.html', classActive=classActives, user=user, questions=questions_list)


 @app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
 def login():
    current_user = get_current_user()

    errors = {'error_password': 'None', 'error_email': 'None'}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form['useremail']
        password = request.form['userpassword']

        user_result = Users.query.filter(Users.email == email).first()
        user = {'id': user_result.id, 'name': user_result.name, 'email': user_result.email,
            'password': user_result.password, 'expert': user_result.expert, 'admin': 
        user_result.admin}

    if user:
        if check_password_hash(user['password'], password):
            session['user'] = user['name']
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        else:
            errors['error_password'] = 'password do not match'
    else:
        errors['error_email'] = 'Email dont exist'

return render_template('login.html', errors=errors, classActive=classActives, user=current_user)


@app.route('/register', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def register():
   current_user = get_current_user()

user_created = None
error = {'name': 'None', 'email': 'None'}

if request.method == 'POST':

    existing_user = Users.query.order_by(db.and_(Users.name, Users.email)).filter(
        db.or_(Users.name == request.form['username'],
               Users.email == request.form['useremail'])).first()

    user = {'id': existing_user.id, 'name': existing_user.name, 'email': existing_user.email,
            'password': existing_user.password, 'expert': existing_user.expert, 'admin': 
    existing_user.admin}

    if user:
        if user['name'] == request.form['username']:
            error['name'] = 'this name already exist'
            user_created = False
        elif user['email'] == request.form['useremail']:
            error['email'] = 'this email already exist'
            user_created = False
    else:
        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(request.form['userpassword'], method='sha256')
        created_user = Users(name=request.form['username'], email=request.form['useremail'],
                             password=hashed_password, expert=0, admin=0)
        db.session.add(created_user)
        db.session.commit()
        user_created = True
        session['user'] = request.form['username']
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

return render_template('register.html', error=error, user_created=user_created,
                       classActive=classActives, user=current_user)


@app.route('/askquestion', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def ask():
   return 'html'


@app.route('/answers/<question_id>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def answers(question_id):
   return 'html'


@app.route('/unanswered')
def unanswered():
   return 'html'


@app.route('/questions/<question_id>')
def questions(question_id):
   return 'html'


@app.route('/users')
def users_control():
   return 'html'


@app.route('/promote/<user_id>')
def promote(user_id):
   return 'html'


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
  return 'html'
```

the database.py file

```
from src.app import db


class Users(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True),
   name = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=True, nullable=False)
   email = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
   password = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
   expert = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
   admin = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

def __repr__(self):
    return '<User %r' % self.name


class Questions(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   question_text = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
   answer_text = db.Column(db.String(150))
   expert_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
   asked_by_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)

   asker = db.relationship('Users', foreign_keys=[asked_by_id], lazy=False)
   expert = db.relationship('Users', foreign_keys=[expert_id], lazy=False)

   def __repr__(self):
      return '<Question %r' % self.id


   def init_db():
      db.create_all()
```

and I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:/Users/hp/Travaux/test-al/run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src import app
  File "C:\Users\hp\Travaux\test-al\src\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .app import app
  File "C:\Users\hp\Travaux\test-al\src\app\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .app import app, db
  File "C:\Users\hp\Travaux\test-al\src\app\app.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .database import Users, Questions
  File "C:\Users\hp\Travaux\test-al\src\app\database\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .database import Questions, Users, db , init_db
  File "C:\Users\hp\Travaux\test-al\src\app\database\database.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src.app import db
ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from 'src.app' (C:\Users\hp\Travaux\test-al\src\app\__init__.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You are having circular imports, a common problem in Flask.

Comment: so How I can fix that

Comment: Hi bryan could you share full code including the `__init__.py` on all directory or your repository so we could help?